# spring boot 2 data jpa generated query is wrong

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities `Transaction` and `Statement`, I'm trying to find transactions that have no statement associated with,

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@MappedSuperclass
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
abstract class Template implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    .... auditing equals and hash methods here

}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Transaction extends Template {

    .... more here

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "transaction")
    private Statement statement;

}
```

```
@Entity
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Statement extends Template {

.... more here

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Transaction transaction;


}
```

```
@RepositoryRestResource
interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, String> {

    //@Query("select transaction from Transaction transaction where statement is null ")
    Collection<Transaction> findByStatementIsNull();

}
```

With or without `@Query` provided to JpaRepository this same query is generating which is wrong, as it is looking for `where transactio0_.id is null` while it should be looking for `statement is null`

```
select transactio0_.id as id1_45_, transactio0_.created_date as created_2_45_, transactio0_.creator as creator3_45_, transactio0_.modified_date as modified4_45_, transactio0_.modifier as modifier5_45_, transactio0_.aggregate_id as aggrega16_45_, transactio0_.amount as amount6_45_, transactio0_.billing_address_id as billing17_45_, transactio0_.blacklisted as blacklis7_45_, transactio0_.connection_id as connect18_45_, transactio0_.credit_card_id as credit_19_45_, transactio0_.currency as currency8_45_, transactio0_.customer_id as custome20_45_, transactio0_.description as descript9_45_, transactio0_.device_id as device_21_45_, transactio0_.electronic_check_id as electro22_45_, transactio0_.fraud_status as fraud_s10_45_, transactio0_.gateway_id as gateway23_45_, transactio0_.independent_sales_organization_id as indepen24_45_, transactio0_.issue_payment_id as issue_p25_45_, transactio0_.merchant_id as merchan26_45_, transactio0_.order_id as order_i11_45_, transactio0_.process_type as process12_45_, transactio0_.recurring_id as recurri27_45_, transactio0_.shipping_address_id as shippin28_45_, transactio0_.store_id as store_i29_45_, transactio0_.transaction_id as transac13_45_, transactio0_.transaction_status as transac14_45_, transactio0_.transaction_type as transac15_45_, transactio0_.wallet_account_id as wallet_30_45_ 
from billing_transaction transactio0_ 
where transactio0_.id is null
```

I'm not sure this is a bug in Spring Data JPA or I'm doing something wrong here, this used to work fine in Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE but having this issue after upgrade to spring boot v2.0.3.RELEASE

spring boot v2.0.3.RELEASE dependencies are
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.0.3.RELEASE
hibernate.version 5.2.17.Final

Comment: If you use `@Query` Spring Data (mostly) just passes the query to the JPA implementation. So this sounds like in the SQL generation of the JPA implementation something is wrong. You might want to tag the question with the JPA implementation used and add the version of the implementation. Also twiddling with that version might help.